# What is a Hibernate dirty session?

Tags: java, hibernate

I was wondering if anybody could tell me what a hibernate dirty session is? I seem to be having an issue where a criteria query is performing an insert when it shouldn't. I believe it's related to a dirty session, but without knowing truly what a dirty session is, I'm unable to resolve my issue. Also, how do you create a dirty session. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Hibernate session is a cache. It caches entities read from the database, and it also caches changes you've made to entities it contains, as well as added and removed entities, until the session is flushed (i.e. all the pending changes are written to the database).

A session is said *dirty* when some changes have not been flushed yet. And it's thus perfectly normal to have a dirty session. The session is flushed before the transaction is committed.

Comment: if I don't want the query to trigger a flush, should I set the criteria query setFlushMode to manual, or would you concider this a band aid fix?

Comment: @George if you don't want to save the changes made to objects, try to do those changes outside the session

Comment: I guess I'll have to look for some additional information on how to store my data outside of the session. I'm still pretty new to hibernate, so not entirely sure how it's getting into the session to began with.

Comment: "The session is flushed before the transaction is committed."Only when flushmode is not set to manual. @JB Nizet No?

Comment: @SachinVerma yes, or course. But that's not the default.

Comment: @JB, OpenSessionInViewFilter does set session.flushmode to manual and it's common nowadays.

Answer (score 7):

A dirty session in Hibernate is when you load an object inside the session and then modifies it.

Or, when you open a session and create a new object.

Even if you don't explicitily call any insert/update operation, Hibernate marks the session as **dirty** and saves the changes when the session is closed

Answer (score 4):

In simple words: As we know Dirty data is the one which is not yet committed. In the same way dirty session in hibernate contains modified data which is not yet committed.

Answer (score 2):

It just means you have made changes to in-memory, managed, persistent objects, that have not yet been flushed to the database.

Basically the idea behind hibernate is that the state of the in memory persistent objects *is* the state of the application.  If you make a change to a managed object, hibernate is going to put that in the database at the next opportunity.  You should not make 'temporary' changes to managed objects that you do not intend to become persistent, because they will be!

Before executing a query, hibernate flushes the in memory state of all managed objects to the database, so that the query is accurate relative to the state of your application.

Comment: Actually, it's more complicated than that: Hibernate flushes only if the pending changes could have an impact on the executed query.

Comment: Is there a recommended way to prevent the query from performing an insert before I tell it to insert the object? I used setFetchMode to manual which worked, however I feel this might just be a band aid fix rather than a root fix.

Comment: The FlushMode can be changed for the entire application at the SessionFactory, probably to COMMIT, not MANUAL, if you don't want it ever doing inserts and updates before the end of the transaction.  That is the fix though, if you're making changes to managed entities that you don't want written to the database, not just a bandaid.

Comment: @JB, true, for some reason I thought ALWAYS was the default, not AUTO